# Write Facebook Comment in Android App

Tags: android, facebook

I am using Facebook plugin to show comment box. 
I am facing problem with facebook session maintenance i.e if user logins using facebook dialog(browser),then user is able to comment in the comment box in my app.
But If the Facebook login in the app was done using the native Facebook application, then the user is prompted to first login to comment in the comment box, which is some what weird for user since he/she already did the Facebook login initially.

The reason for it may be that facebook login using facebook native app and dialog may return different auth tokens. 
Is there any way I can use native fb token for browser fb login?
Please if somebody can help in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible. The Facebook for Android application and the Facebook login through your browser on your device share different sessions and the session from one is not able to access the session from the other. Your users will need to login to their Facebook account through their mobile browsers in order to comment directly on your page.

However in the next release of the Comments plugin Facebook will soon be introducing comment mirroring to the comments plugin which will allow you to share the same comment thread on your Facebook Page that you are having on your site.

This new product is highlighted here and is currently in beta: https://developers.facebook.com/products/social-plugins/comments/